# Psycopg2 copy_expert returns different results than direct query

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I am trying to debug this issue that I have been having for a couple of weeks now. I am trying to copy the result of a query in a Postgresql db into a csv file using psycopg2 and copy expert, however when my script finishes running, sometimes I end up with less rows than if I ran the query directly into the db using pgAdmin. This is the code that runs the query and saves it into a csv:

```
cursor = pqlconn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

fd = open("query.sql", 'r')
sql_query = fd.read()

fd.close()
csv_path = 'test.csv'
query = "copy  (" + sql_query + \
    ") TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ',', HEADER)"
with open(csv_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:

    cursor.copy_expert(query, f_output)
print("Saved information to csv: ", csv_path)`
```

When it runs I will sometimes end up with less rows than if I ran it directly on the db, running it again still returns less rows than what I am already seeing in the db directly. Would appreciate any guidance on this, thanks!

Comment: We are going to need to see the contents of `query.sql` as that is the part governing what is returned from the database. Add as update to your question. Also are you sure that you are looking at the same database or table in `pgAdmin` vs your `psycopg2` script?  In other words is `pqlconn` pointing at the same database as the connection parameters in `pgAdmin`. If it is are you sure you are pointing at the same schema.table in both cases? Again update your question with your answers.

Comment: Hi Adrian appreciate your response. I was able to fix this. Realized that it was an issue with the path I was using to save the csv to the cloud at a later point in my program which made it point to an earlier version of the file. Thanks for your help.